# unable to create WSO2 CEP RDBMS Datasource

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, wso2, complex-event-processing

I am trying to configure WSO2 CEP to store the events to database table.

1. I have created Event Stream/Receiver,
2. I would like publish the Stream on a External Database using Datasource.

i am getting the below error while I trying to create Datasource to mysql or oracle

for mysql datasource

**ERROR: Error in creating external data source: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.1**

for oracle datasource

**ERROR: Error in creating external data source: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.1**

Can anyone help me fix this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this issue is due to the missing database drivers in {$HOME}/repsitory/components/lib folder. Can you please check if the relevant database drivers are placed in this directory? You can find the documentation regarding setting up MySql and Oracle databases with CEP, respectively at [1] and [2]. Hope this helps.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Setting+up+MySQL
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Setting+up+Oracle

Cheers,
Pubudu.